# How to add more information in jwt?

Tags: angular, express, authentication, jwt, nestjs

I used [this tutorial here](https://dev.to/thisdotmedia/angular-and-the-rest-nest-js-and-jwt-dja) and now I wonder how I can add additional Infos to this token? I want to have a field called 'accessRights' that I can use to authorify a user in the backend and also wihtin angular.

Where do I Need to add this field? (The Content of this field Comes from the db so I guess it could be somewhere in the validateUser?)

Comment: You can add it in the payload of JWT

Answer (score 0):

you can add as many data in a token you want.

```
 const token = jwt.sign({
       email: user.email,
       id: user.id, 
       role: user.role,
       fistName: user.firstName, 
       lastName: user.lastName,
       status: user.status, 
       softDelete: user.softDelete,
       access_rights : 'Your Rights'
    }, 'your secret', { expiresIn: 30000000 * 60 });
```

and when you decode it all the data will be available in the decoded token.